# How can I prevent a ShowDialog form to close himself and all the chain who called him?

Tags: showdialog

It seems that if just something goes wrong all the Showdialog forms close like a chain.
[By the way I have a main panel from which after login brings to another panel/form (ShowDialog form) who can bring to another panel/form (ShowDialog form) for password change... All of those forms close abruptly if something goes wrong and the program goes back to main panel...]

Thanks!

Comment: Any alternative way?